# Drawing a partially coiled rope in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to illustrate a classic physics problem where a rope that is coiled on the ground is lifted by one end until it is vertical; a quick online search turned up [this hand-drawn sketch](https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fc4e%2Fc4e6f6f8-addf-4384-8798-3e06808ffa80%2Fimage). Is it possible to create a similar sketch using tikz?

Comment: I haven't coded anything so far because I'm not sure where to start. I wondered about trying a 3dplot in tikz with a spiral (drawn in polar coordinates) on the plane, and a line going up the vertical axis, but I thought that a physicist might have a more attractive solution :)

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\begin{document} 
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{100} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,tdplot_main_coords] 
 \coordinate (T) at (0,0,5);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5) ;
  \draw plot[variable=\t,domain=1800:0,samples=361,smooth] ({cos(\t)*\t/1000},{sin(\t)*\t/1000})
  [rounded corners] to (T);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot That's exactly what I was looking for! And much more elegant than what I was going to do - thank you! :)